# Problems with cookie which saves user navigation

Tags: php, cookies

I am very new to php and this is the first time i use cookies. I am trying to create a cookie which will save user navigation inside my website. I have one page called Home, and one page called Feedback.

Problems:

1. When loading the webpage for the first time, php shows this error (ErrorException
   Undefined index: nav_history). When page is refreshed it works properly, showing the pages name (Home or Feedback)
2. When navigating from Home to Feedback (or vice versa, but lets take Home to Feedback for example) the page will print Home (when it should print Feedback) and then if i refresh this page, Feedback is added below Home. I want it to show Feedback on the first try.

Code for home:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['nav_history'])) {
  $cookie_values = $_COOKIE["nav_history"];
  $cookie_values .= "Home<br>";

  setcookie("nav_history", $cookie_values, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
} elseif (!isset($_COOKIE["nav_history"])) {
  setcookie("nav_history", "Home<br>", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}

echo $_COOKIE['nav_history'];
?>
```

Code for feedback page

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['nav_history'])) {
  $cookie_values = $_COOKIE["nav_history"];
  $cookie_values .= "Feedback<br>";

  setcookie("nav_history", $cookie_values, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
} elseif (!isset($_COOKIE["nav_history"])) {
  setcookie("nav_history", "Feedback<br>", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}

echo $_COOKIE['nav_history'];
?>
```

I have this feeling both problem scenarios can be fixed with the same change in code. Sorry if my explaining is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['nav_history'])) {
  $cookie_values = $_COOKIE["nav_history"];
  $cookie_values .= "Feedback<br>";

  setcookie("nav_history", $cookie_values, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
} elseif (!isset($_COOKIE["nav_history"])) {
  setcookie("nav_history", "Feedback<br>", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}

echo $cookie_values ?? ''; //this line had to be changed.

?>
```